# problem to recover the value of an input [javascript, php]

Tags: javascript, php, input

The employee must not exceed 100€ of product, so I wanted him to write down the quantity of product he wants, press a button and a dialog box appears to display the total price of the order. 
I managed to have the price of the item displayed for each product in the dialog box and to have the prices for each chosen product added together.

However, I cannot recover the value of the input which is the quantity chosen by the employee.

```
    $lenum = 0;
      foreach ($lesProduits as $leProduit){
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $leProduit['image'];?>">
        <br><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $leProduit['nproduit']?>" name="nproduits[]" value="<?php echo $leProduit['nproduit']?>">
        <?php echo $leProduit['nproduit']; ?> - <?php echo $leProduit['designation']; ?><br>
        Boitage : <?php echo $leProduit['boitage'];?><br>
        Prix Unitaire : <?php echo $leProduit['prix']; ?>€<br>
        Quantité : <?php echo $leProduit['qtestock'];  ?> <br>
        Quantité souhaité :  <input type="text" name="txtqte[]" id="<?php echo $lenum;?>"  size="3"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Enregistrer" onclick="leprix(lep = <?php echo $leProduit['prix'];?>,<?php echo $lenum;?>)">
        <br>
        <hr><br>
        <?php
        $lenum ++;
      }
      ?>
```

and the script

```
function leprix(lep,inputId){
    var lavaleur = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
    alert("la prix du produit est de : " + lep);
    alert("la quantité demandé est de : " + lavaleur);
}
```

For the first product when $lenum = 0 it works but then it displays $lenum and not the value of the input

Comment: `<input type="text" name="txtqte[]" name="<?php echo $lenum;?>"  size="3"/>`

you should provide an `id`

Comment: You're outputting a `function leprix` during every iteration of the PHP loop. Only the last iteration of that function will actually "survive" and overwrite all previous ones. So `onclick="leprix()"` won't call the specific `function leprix` "of that iteration", but the last one.

Comment: Try this: ```<input type="text" name="txtqte[]" name="<?php echo $lenum;?>" size="3" id="<?php echo $lenum;?>">```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
   <input type="text" name="txtqte[]" name="<?php echo $lenum;?>" id="<?php echo $lenum;?>"  size="3"/>
   <input type="button" value="Enregistrer" onclick="leprix('<?php echo $lenum;?>')">
   <script>
       function leprix(inputId){
            var input = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
            alert(input);
       }
   </script>
```

Comment: And take that `<script>...</script>` out of the PHP loop…

Comment: the name I can't change it it serves me for the next page which is the shopping cart. On the other hand this method works for the product 1 it works but for the others it shows me $lenum and not the value of the input

Comment: @ZinebMouazzaz I am not saying to change the name, just add the id attribute and use that id as parameter in JavaScript function.

Comment: @deceze I got the script out of the loop, I put it in a separate file, and when I do this I can only display the first product with $lenum = 0 otherwise it displays the variable and not the result of the input I don't understand.